# Every finitely generated $R$-module has simple quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules

Claim: Every non-trivial finitely generated $R$-module has a non-trivial simple quotient.

How to prove this? I was able to show that a $R$-module is simple if and only if it is isomorphic to a module of the form $R/m$ where $m$ is maximal. Is this helpful to prove the above claim?

Answer (score 2):

This is the same as proving that such a module $M$ has a maximal
non-trivial submodule $N$. You can prove this by a Zorn's lemma argument
in much the same way as one proves a ring has a maximal ideal. The finite
generation of $M$ is important.